# adding an existing folder to clickonce deploy

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

i'd like to create a clickonce installation for my apllication in VS2012 c#.

my main project (startup project) doesn't include all projects reference because uses project dependencies.
My output release is made through post build action.
These post build actions create a release output tree directory (with several files and dll i need for installation) and i 'd like to maintein this configuration dir after deploy with clickonce.

i'd like to know if i can add my release dir in clickonce installation including all sub directory, withouth adding each file manually (to avoid manually maintain deploy manifest when adding new files to build).
I would like to provide to clickonce just the root tree directory, supposing clickonce includes all sub folder in the deployed package.

have you any idea?

i have tried to install clickonce setup with my actual configuration but it doesn't work beacuse it is missing of all references in main project (I'm using dependencies to build all the projects) and so program starts loading main page but crash when calling missing dlls (that in visual studio enviroment works because are copied by post build action)
i cannot add all reference in main project because i cannot change build configuration.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

have you tried going to:

- Project Properties->Publish->Application Files...
- then choose your file and select Include

if the file you require is not there:

- Select your file in the Solution Explorer
- Right click and select Properties
- find the "Copy to Output Directory" and select "Copy always"

Comment: i wouldn't like to select each file or project but use the root tree output dir like link or path

Comment: i haven't tried it with folders but i think it will be similar, move files to a folder(in case you haven't) then choose the copy output directory select always, this must work!

Comment: folders haven't "copy to output directory" property

Comment: if you have putted the files in to the folder than follow these steps:
Project Properties->Publish->Application Files-> select include all files that are inside the folder ex:
folder name: Test
File names: TestFile1,TestFile2
you will see something like this:
Test\TestFile1
Test\TestFile2
and in the same row with those you can select Include(if the include isn't selected).
That's the only way that it worked for me, it was with the folder

Comment: but in this way you have to includ each file in "Test File" and every time you add a file in solution, you have to add also in publish properties. i have to much file to insert manually , for this reason i wish publish only root folder name and not files included in this root folder

Comment: everytime you import a file to that directory you need to make sure you have selected Copy always in the file properties, that's the only way i have seen, if that doesn't work then you need to go to publish properties and select include

Comment: i don't want to add these files in project. suppose i have my project in c:\myProject\myproject.cs and my postbuild output in d:\MyRelease; i would set as link or path to MyRelease dir without adding all directory in myProject